# Find out the working folder in a Foundation executable?

Tags: cocoa, foundation

I have a console program which is linked to the **Foundation** framework on Mac. How do I find out the **folder** the executable is in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though the tool is not in a bundle, you can still use some of the `NSBundle` methods.  For example:

```
NSString * binaryPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] executablePath];
NSString * executableFolder = [binaryPath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
```

Answer (score 1):

What about `[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]`

Comment: The executable is not in a bundle. It is a standalone mach executable.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument passed to main() ( `argv[0]` ) is the path to the executable itself. If you wrote said console program, you could get it that way.

Comment: Only if you invoke the program by full path. If you put the program somewhere along your PATH (say, by installing it), then run it by name alone, `argv[0]` will be only the name.

Comment: Hmmm. I thought under BSD it was always the full path. I'm not sure where I read that and can't find any reference to it, so I suppose it was merely an assumption on my part. Good to know.